# Is android supported FLASH action script 2.0?

Tags: android, air, flash

I have build one application in which I want to `load SWF file` build in `action-script 2
.0`(user interactive like game).
problem is when I am view "**.apk**" in `android emulator` or `AdobeAir emulator` its not display.
same thing when I have try with `Action script 3.0`it is view correctly. 
so any **suggestion or solution**?

have any idea that android support action script 2.0 ?if yes then how?

thanks.
 nik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, this is not possible. taken from the release notes of AIR2.5:

`In AIR for Android, you can use the Loader class to load a SWF file and execute its code. (However, ActionScript 2.0 is not supported.) AIR applications for the iPhone cannot execute code in loaded SWF content; AIR for Android does not include this restriction.`

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/868/cpsid_86822.html

Comment: this is talking about android air, but if we focus only android then is it possible to support 2.0

Comment: another question are raise in mind is that adobeflashplayer10.3 support 2.0 ?

Comment: if you want to compile for use in the android browser, AS2 should work with flashplayer 10.3 (and lower)